# Doesn't this question belong on "English Language & Usage"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, off-topic

[Is 'temping' a culture-specific term?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/26669/is-temping-a-culture-specific-term?rq=1)

This question is regarding whether *temping* is culture-specific term. Isn't this a single-word question belonging on *English Language & Usage*? I am quite unsure, since no-one mentioned this in a comment under the question. If it does belong here, is there a part of *Writing* I am unaware of?

Comment: Note: I edited the post you link to to fix the tags.  I didn't touch the title/body.

Comment: Questions that are over 60 days old can't be migrated. It might not have faired too well on ELU if it was migrated in time though because it looks like it can be answered by just looking it up in the dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On its own, it's a question for English.

But the longer question does connect to a fictional setting and it's reasonable to ask in a writing context.  If someone new to SE were coming in with that question asking where to post it, I'd probably direct them to English.  But given the story context, it's not unreasonable to have it on Writing.

> I have a character working in a short-term temporary position in an
>   organisation and refer to her doing the work using the usual UK word,
>   'temping'. Will this be understood by readers in the US and other
>   English-speaking cultures? If not, is there an equivalent
>   culture-neutral term or should I spell it out?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the question ever belonged to ELL. In fact, it seems to me that the OP already knows the meaning and usage of the word.

The question is about whether the use of a certain word would be understood by the readers in the context of a written text, and, if not, how to rewrite it in a way that it would be understood. In this sense it is akin to the discussion about the Aluminium/Aluminum conundrum.